# Heroku and Rails 4: Heroku isn't finding my nested folder under assets/javascripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm running an app on Heroku, and just recently upgrade to rails 4. At first the assets weren't loading, but then I added `gem 'rails_12factor'` to the Gemfile, and that seemed to fix it. However, in one of my files, I have a javascript file specific to that page I need to load. I do it by doing:

`= javascript_include_tag "registrations/registrations.js"`

which in Rails 3 would find the file under `app/assets/javascripts/registrations/registrations.js`

It works fine locally - however, on Heroku it doesn't seem to find the file correctly. How would I go about fixing it?

Note: I can't add the file to the main directory where application.js is, since it messes up the page layout of other pages.

Comment: what does Heroku reference `javascript_include_tag "registrations/registrations.js"` as? I'm having a similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935738/heroku-rails-4-not-referencing-my-javascript-assets-location-correctly

Comment: Are you precompiling your assets before you push to heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your GEMFILE

```
group :heroku do
  gem 'rails_log_stdout', github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
  gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
end
```

If that doesn't work, here is my Rails 4 app on Heroku.
https://github.com/andey/bestofama . Feel free to browse the config for any differences