# Heroku Rails 4 not referencing my JavaScript assets location correctly

Tags: javascript, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

My local development runs fine, rendering `javascript_include_tag "some-script"` as referencing `/assests/some-script.js` correctly.

In Heroku, it references `/javascripts/some-script.js`

I'm using `gem 'rails_12factor'` in production in my `Gemfile`

Do I need to change any asset configuration settings? Like precompiling assets? I'm aware there are several config settings, but I'm unsure when to use them, in the past I've been fine without modifying them ([like this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18845753/1183537)).

It's just odd it references the `/javascripts` folder...

Also, to note, I am not currenty using `javascript_include_tag "application"` in `layout/application.html.erb` I am importing scripts manually using `javascript_include_tag "some-script"` in specific view erb files

Secondly, `/assets/some-script.js` comes up as a 404, so this must means my assests aren't available, which could be a second issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18470309/1183537) may resolve my issue  attempting it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469776/heroku-and-rails-4-some-javascript-not-working/18470309#18470309) helped me resolve my issue. I had to manually add the js files to the assets precompile list in `config/environments/production.rb` like so:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( some-script.js )
config.assets.precompile += %w( some-script2.js )
...
```

When I use a script in a view `javascript_include_tag "some-script"` works.